# How to customize Error Pages on prod environment without debug on Symfony 4.0

Tags: custom-error-pages, symfony4

I know there is similar question on stackoverflow but they are for previous version of symfony and I didn't find any solution to my problem.

I've just migrated from symfony 3.3 to symfony 4.0 and I can't manage to migrate customization of error pages.

I did what is explained on https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html.
So I put an `error.html.twig` file, an `error404.html.twig` file and an `exception.html.twig` file on `templates\bundles\TwigBundle\Exception` repository.

In my prod environment, it's working just fine when debug is true. It uses `exception.html.twig` template. But when debug is false, it didn't work and the default symfony template is displayed instead of mine.

I can't find any idea why? Do you?

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

1) Check ownership & permissions on your templates and template directories. From the templates directory, you could:

```html
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data *
```

2) Then shut off debugging in your .env file by removing the APP_DEBUG line, or setting it to false:

```html
APP_ENV=prod
APP_DEBUG=false
```

3) Finally, in the project root, clear the Symfony cache:

```html
bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: HI thank you for your answer. It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `APP_DEBUG=0` in your `.env` file

Note that `APP_DEBUG=false` didn't work for me in Symfony 4

See : https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html#index-3

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. It didn't work for me.